# Where-Object optimization Powershell

Tags: powershell, filtering

I have this command which works correctly:

```
$FichierXML = get-childitem "$PsScriptRoot" | Where-Object { ($_.Name -notlike "creer*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "des*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "ins*")  -and ($_.Name -like "*.XML") }
```

It finds the .XML file which does not contain in it's name the 3 words "creer", "des", and "ins".

My question is, is there an optimal way of doing this instead of multiple conditions in the where-object like I'm doing? A short way perhaps? Of course it's fine like this but i'm always curious to learn better methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$FichierXML = Get-ChildItem "$PsScriptRoot" -Filter '*.XML' | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch '^(creer|des|ins)' }
```

Use the `-Filter` parameter to get only `.XML` files and use regular expression `-notmatch` for the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

There are `-in` and `-notin` operators but they check multiple values for exact matches. Nothing like `-notlikein` or anything like that.

Not 100%, but believe this should work:

```
$FichierXML = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot" |
                Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(creer|des|ins)" -and $_.Name -like "*.XML"}
```

**Explanation:**

- `-[not]match` uses regex, `-[not]like` does not
- `|` acts as logical "or"
- `^` specifies beginning of string
- `()` are expanded out so you have `^creer`, `^des`,`^ins`

**Related:** [Operators documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators)

**edit**: incorporated corrections from [Matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632992/where-object-optimization-powershell/53633323?noredirect=1#comment94126118_53633323)

Comment: Your regex might not work the way you expect it. It would match Ingress and Insssssstant for example. Also I would get the start of line anchor out of the alternate match group

Comment: Thanks - the `*` was a typo and it looks like Theo has posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53633353/5039142) with the anchor out of the "or". For my own benefit, why would Ingress be matched?

Comment: because `s*` would match _0 or more_ times. Effectively saying anything that starts with "in"